# How should I interpret the Activity Monitor "Open Files and Ports" output?

Tags: macos, process

I'm trying to debug a file descriptor leak in a program. I'm looking at Activity Monitor's "Open Files and Ports" window in hopes of gleaning some information.

I see several types of entries. Here's a sample:

```
cwd
/
txt
/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app/Contents/MacOS/Activity Monitor
0
/dev/null
1
/dev/null
2
/dev/null
3
4
5
6
7
->0x1c8e9b47ad822e5b
```

I believe that I understand several things about this format:

- In general, a first line tells the file descriptor and the second line shows where it points:

  - `cwd /` means that the current directory of the app is /
  - `txt /Applications/.../Activity Monitor` means that "Activity Monitor" is mapped into memory without having an open file descriptor
  - `0 /dev/null` means that file descriptor 0 is associated to /dev/null
  - `7 ->0x1c8e9b47ad822e5b` means that file descriptor 7 is associated to a file-like object that doesn't have a persistent name (?)

But what about file descriptors 3 through 6? What are they associated to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity Monitor shows the result of `lsof -Fn -p [pid]`, stripping the first character from each line. The meaning of a missing file entry remains unclear, but regular possibilities are shown in the lsof man page (`man lsof` in the terminal) under the NAME section.